# Spring Kafka and Re-balancing in the Middle of Processing

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, transactions, spring-kafka

In this link https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html the section entitled, "Consuming Records with Specific Offsets" makes reference to a strategy of effectively updating the topic partition offsets in an external store "as you go", and then on partition revocation (e.g. a re-balancing) simply commit any interrupted transaction to the external store.

Now, I'm assuming that this strategy means that in the partition revocation callback that I don't need to process the passed-in TopicPartition collection for the offsets as any "in progress" transaction that was interrupted will be persisted and will contain the partition offsets that need to be committed/saved.

(If I'm wrong on this, please correct me.)

So, then, given that this is Spring Kafka and I'm making use of an @Transactional service to persist the necessary data, is the above strategy relevant/doable? In other words, I'm unsure of how I'd resume/commit anything marked as @Transactional since the transaction manager, boundary, etc. is all taken care of under the hood.

Is this even an issue? If so, what would be the best way to achieve this strategy? Manually track transactions (which sounds horrible across methods and callbacks)?

Or should I just go through the TopicPartition collection on partition revocation and update the partition offsets anyway?

Hopefully this makes sense as I'd like to make sure I get this right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Released September 2017

That book is quite old in Kafka terms; with modern versions; keeping the offsets in Kafka is much simpler; just make sure your consumer can process all the records returned by a `poll()` within `max.poll.interval.ms` in order to avoid a rebalance altogether.

Comment: My concern is something like new partitions being created while running, or consumers failing and/or joining (e.g. restarting the Spring application): In those cases, because I don't want to start from earliest (have to implement duplicate checking), if it's at "latest" and a message comes in to Kafka before the application is back up (or a consumer is assigned to the partition), that message will be lost. In a way that's also a type of re-balance. If this is dated thinking, I'd be most grateful if you could point me at a more modern resource/book. Thanks again.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor Why would messages be lost? They are retained for a week, by default. Also, if you add partitions, then host partitions are empty until data is produced. You should definitely start at earliest to read all relevant data.

Comment: @Gary that section of the book was more highlighting the capabilities of storing offsets in an external store. It is still relevant, although maybe uncommon

Comment: @cricket_007 Not so much "lost" as "unprocessed" by a consumer, since when a consumer is subsequently assigned to the partition, unless I seek to the proper position, the consumer won't see the awaiting message, i.e. with "auto offset reset" set to "latest". If it's set to earliest, then I have to write code to ensure that I don't duplicate the processing previously done on the replayed messages, e.g. don't want to store the same records in the database when they were previously processed and inserted.

Comment: I'm also curious as to why what the book said, while still relevant, is uncommon. I'd love to know of a better way to ensure offsets are preserved during re-balancing and partition assignment, unless you're saying that replaying from "earliest" and adding appropriate "don't duplicate" logic in the consumer is the best way to go instead.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor The book was written before transactional / idempotent producers existed. There is little drawbacks to storing offsets the way they are in Kafka. If you are producing the same exact event more than once, though, that is an entirely separate issue.

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html also speaks of storing offsets in the same store as the output of the consumer (the documentation looks current). In my case it’s a database and not another Kafka topic (apologies if that wasn’t clear). So either my original questions still stand, or I have to ensure the messages have some form of primary key so I can deduplicate on partition assignment and thereby avoid storing the offsets in the external store.

Comment: `auto.offset.reset` applies only when there is no committed offset for a topic/partition for a consumer `group.id`. After a rebalance, you will only see records from a partition beyond that offset. With Spring, if the listener container ackMode is `RECORD`, the offset is committed when the listener returns. With the default `BATCH`, they are queued up and committed when all records returned from the poll are completed. If there is a rebalance, any "pending" offset are committed during the rebalance (during the revoke phase). It is true, however, that there is a small possibility of duplicates.

Comment: `>Or should I just go through the TopicPartition collection on partition revocation and update the partition offsets anyway?` If you store the partition/offset in the DB, you don't need to do anything on revocation; simply perform the appropriate DB lookup and seeks during assignment.

Comment: @Gary Russell thank you for all the info it’s a huge help. So, just so I’m clear, in my case, given that I’m storing the output of the consumer to an external DB, is the best thing to do to store the offsets in that database? Or is that dependent on my tolerance for potential duplicates? Again I appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: Yes; it's a trade-off between the small (but non-zero) probability of a duplicate delivery (and adding code to handle that) Vs. the added complexity of managing the offsets (and performing seeks after a rebalance) yourself.

Comment: Some good sources of knowledge on these topics

 * https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/
 * https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/issues/369
 * https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/issues/382
 * https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/pull/420